# Creating one unique instance of a class, when there are several implementations for it

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

Let's say I have 2 classes A1, A2 which are supposed to implement the same functionality differently (lets assume they both implement a void f() method).

In my application I use only one of them at a time.

In order to do so, I created an interface A with the method f(), and let A1&A2 inherit it.

Then, I thought about creating a singleton called AHolder, which at any given time will hold exactly one A class (A1 or A2). AHolder will determine the instance type of its A class by reading from configuration.

The thing is, I would like to implement this in a way that doesn't allow to create more than one A class (Even if I create A1&A2 singletons - I still can create one instance of each - which means 2 instances of A class...)

Is there an elegant way of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

this way you will have only one instance at a time.

```
public class AHolder {

 private static A instance;

 private AHolder() {
 }

  public synchronized static A getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
       if (Config.getAHolderType() == "A1") {
          instance = new A1();
       } else if (Config.getAHolderType() == "A2") {
          instance = new A2();
       } else {
         throw new IllegalStateException("class type not specified");
       } 
    }

   return instance;
  }
```

Comment: that way A1&A2 's constructor has to be public. This means that everyone can call new A1() or new A2() creating a second instance of it...

Comment: you can make it package private...put AHolder and A1 and A2 in the same package...and don't put 'public' on the constructors of A1 and A2. That way, only the classes in that package will be able to instantiate these classes.

Comment: It's a good idea, but it doesn't keep someone (say another programmer) from instantiating another instance of the classes if he works on that specific package... I wonder if there is a solution that will keep the instance unique for sure (like the Singleton pattern for one instance type).

Comment: If you really wanna enforce that in another level, you can make A1 and A2 singletons by themselves...this way, the AHolder would be like a factory just enabling external user to instantiate the correct object based on the configuration.

Comment: You're right - but still someone could instantiate both A1 and A2 at the same time...